# How can I lookup an attribute in any scope by name?

Tags: python

How can I lookup an attribute in any scope by name? My first trial is to use globals() and locals(). e.g.

```
>>> def foo(name):
...   a=1
...   print globals().get(name), locals().get(name)
...
>>> foo('a')
None 1
>>> b=1
>>> foo('b')
1 None
>>> foo('foo')
<function foo at 0x014744B0> None
```

So far so good. However it fails to lookup any built-in names.

```
>>> range
<built-in function range>
>>> foo('range')
None None

>>> int
<type 'int'>
>>> foo('int')
None None
```

Any idea on how to lookup built-in attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> getattr(__builtins__, 'range')
<built-in function range>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `__builtin__` (without the `s` at the end like Triptych and Duncan suggest):

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> getattr(__builtin__, 'range')
<built-in function range>
```

`__builtins__` is [CPython-implementation](http://docs.python.org/library/__builtin__.html) specific thus makes your code less portable.

Comment: Thanks! I did't notice the fine distinction between `__builtins__` and `__builtin__`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__builtins__` "superglobal". It contains exactly what you're looking for